# How to change the headline title for an admin page in a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin

I have a working plug-in, but to add a little polish I would like to add the plug-in title to the `h1` block at the top of the `wrap` container, but ahead of the `admin_notices` list, in the same way that most Wordpress admin pages have. I am sure this is quite easy but without knowing the name it is very hard to find where I can configure this and I can't think of any distinguishing search terms. The `in_admin_header` action is almost in the right place but it is a little early (ahead of the `wrap` container) and obviously that runs on every page. The next event on the list is `admin_notices` which is too late. Also this is such a standard thing I feel like it should have a really basic hook somewhere, that I've just managed to miss.

What do I need to do to give my plugin a standard headline title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to hook anywhere in particular, simply output your heading at the start of your settings page callback and WP should position admin notices appropriately after your heading (there's some logic written into the js/jquery).

For example i have lines like this at the start of various plugin settings pages.

```
<div class="wrap">      
    <h1><?php _e( 'My Plugin Name', 'my_text_domain' ); ?></h1>
    <?php settings_errors(); ?>
```

Some have additional or other markup, but the admin notices, whether they are ***Settings saved*** or error notices will render after the heading if it's inside a wrap element, `<div class="wrap">` in my above sample. You could move the `<?php settings_errors(); ?>` portion of my code above before the heading and WP would move the notice when it's rendered.

<strike>I can't recall off the top of my head where this is done in the core js, but i'll have a dig and edit that info into this answer.</strike>

**Later edit:**

The WP admin javascript **common.js** sets up where notices are produced, here's a link to the portion of code in core.

[wp-admin/js/common.js](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/6.1/src/js/_enqueues/admin/common.js#L1080)

Comment: Oh, wow, it _only_ works if I include the `wrap` div in my plug-in. I assumed I shouldn't do that because Wordpress added that div anyway and it would be weird to have it twice, but apparently if I add that, my plug-in changes the structure of the page and sits where I want it to.

Comment: Updated my answer and linked to the source code so you can see where and how this is done.